# How do I fill/shade a cetain section of my graph in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, physics, graphing

I have a function that I'd like to plot in python and shade the region of interest. I've tried using pyplot.fill_between() but can not quite get what I want. I've attached an image and shaded in orange the region I want to be filled:

[image: Graph with the desired result]

I plot the function (in blue) and then the graph is bounded by y=0, y ≈ 0.05 and x = 0.And I wish to shade the relevant region (in orange).

Any tips as to how to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def fn (M, r_min):
    
    d = (1- 2*M/ r_min)
    x = M/(r_min)**2
    A_0 = d**-0.5
    
    A_dot = np.arange(-0.6,0.5,0.0001) #X axis
    a = np.zeros(len(A_dot)) 
    
    for i in range(1,len(A_dot)):
    
        a[i] = -3*d*A_dot[i]**2 -2*x*A_dot[i] + A_0**2*x**2   #Y axis      
    
    plt.plot(A_dot, a)
    plt.xlim(-0.55,0.55)
    
    plt.axhline(y = 0, color='black', linestyle='--')
    plt.axhline(y = 0.049382716, color = 'black', linestyle = '--')
    plt.axvline(x = 0,color ='black', linestyle = '--')
    idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(a))).flatten() #Finding intersection on x+axis
    plt.plot(A_dot[idx], a[idx], 'ro')
    
    plt.xlabel('$\\frac{dA_0}{d\tau}$')
    plt.ylabel('$|a|^2$')
              
      
    plt.show()
    
    return(A_dot,a)
    
    
fn(1,3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the `x` and `y` vectors as inputs to `fill_between`. To do that, you can define a mask selecting between the interception point and 0 (add to your `fn` function):

```py
x_min = A_dot[idx[1]]
x_max = 0.0
mask_x = np.logical_and(A_dot >= x_min, A_dot <= x_max)
plt.fill_between(x=A_dot[mask_x], y1=a[mask_x], y2=0, color='orange')
```

Result:

[image: Graph with the filled area]